# How to get the same shape or picture in the whole powerpoint file and replace them?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I am using *Visual Studio* and developing an *Office add-in*. I need to identify same shapes and pictures and replace them.

I try to use *OpenXml* to do that but it doesn't seem to be able to be **modified in files in use**. It doesn't seem to work as an office add-in because **it doesn't work with files that are already open**.

And I have searched for many hours on the internet but not found a way to do that.
Help me please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL; DR:** *OpenXML* and *Office add-ins* (including *VSTO*) are competing technologies for different use cases that may lead to runtime issues if combined.  Best to stick to just one.

---

> I am ... developing a office add-in.  I need to identify same shapes and pictures and replace them. I try to use `OpenXml` to do that but **it doesn't seem to be able to be modified in files in use**.

[OpenXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) is an API for *creating/reading/modifying* Office documents ([Office 2010+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) to be exact) that adhere to the contemporary XML document format such as *Word 2010*.  It does so by manipulating the document directly at the *file level* rather than using [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model).  In fact it does not require Word to be installed on the machine at all!  This makes OpenXML a rather light-weight approach to interacting with Office documents.

Unfortunately OpenXML (or other file-based approaches) are unsuitable for Office add-ins (VSTO or otherwise) if both are targeting the same document.  This is because the document is already loaded into say Word and Word is hosting your add-in.  Any attempt to modify the underlying file (including OpenXML by anything but Word or Word APIs) that represents the loaded document will encounter a:

> sharing violation

To put this another way:

1. In order to run your Office add-in the Office app needs to be running first.  This is known as *hosting*
2. Operations on Office documents orchestrated by your add-in require the document to be loaded into the Office app first
3. No *external* Windows process or in-process (add-in) operation can *directly* change the underlying Office document file whilst it is open in the Office app.  (Add-ins can *indirectly* save to the file using Office APIs and ask the Office app to **Save** though generally such APIs don't expose any raw file interfaces to the caller so the later is probably not the same thing)

### What to do?

My recommendation is to either:

**a)** use a pure OpenXML approach and discard the Office add-in *or...*

**b)** use a pure Office add-in (VSTO) approach and discard the OpenXML code

Considering that it seems you already have code for shapes and pictures via the OpenXML approach, perhaps option **a)** is the best.

### See also

- *[Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)*
- *[Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019)*

Comment: Thank you 
If I use Office add-ins approach ,and how do I identify same  picture objects and replace them?

Comment: @RollingDeap24Vz2425 Considering that it seems you already have code for shapes and pictures via the OpenXML approach, perhaps option `a)` is the best.

Comment: Thanks,but I still want to know how to use Office add-ins to do that?Is there any way to get the raw data?

Comment: @RollingDeap24Vz2425 Thanks for accept.  if you want _"raw data"_ then a file-based solution is probably a better approach.  I wouldn't recommend it though preferring VSTO.  Here's an old article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1bf630ad-70a3-4e04-9399-67c64043782f/how-to-get-the-images-from-a-word-document?forum=vsto.  Also see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-add-pictures-and-word-art-to-documents?view=vs-2019).  Don't forget  the upvote if you feel it so as it helps feed the kids ;)